# The line that goes through the point (0, 3/2 ) and is orthogonal to a tangent line to the part of parabola y =x^2 with x > 0 is y = ax + 3/2.

Tags: conic-sections

> 1. Find  the slope $a$ which is in $y=ax+3/2$
> 2. Find the $x$-coordinate of the intersection of the two lines.

Comment: What is your effort so far?

Comment: I found that a= -1/2 and x coordinate (1,1).  I have solved for an hour. I need easy way.step by step

Comment: $y=ax+\frac{3}{2}$ is the given tangent line to $y=x^2$ for $x>0$?

Comment: y=ax +3/2 is the given normal line to y=x^2 for x>0

Comment: For someone to give you a method that you’ll understand, you need to tell us more about what it is that you know how to use: Can you use calculus to find tangents and normals? Do you know about pole-polar relationships? Are you familiar with homogeneous coordinates? I could, for instance write up a method that determines $x$ by finding when a certain matrix determinant vanishes, but if you’re not familiar with the methods that lead to it, it’s not going to be of much use to you.

Comment: My level is pre-calculus. Firtsly ,I drew a graph and found point of intersection of normal line and tangent line on parabola. Then found slope of tangent line which is 2. Lastly,found slope of normal line -1/2. Coefficient " a " in y=ax+ 3/2 is slope. Answer (1,1).   m=a=-1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step approach (as requested in comment to question):

Call the $x$-coordinate of the intersection of the tangent and normal lines $x_0$.

The $y$-coordinate is then $y_0=x_0^2$.

Call $m$ the slope of the tangent line to $y=x^2$ at $x_0$.  What is $m$ in terms of $x_0$?

What is the slope of the normal line at $x_0$?  [Hint:  it is perpendicular to the tangent line.]

What is the $y$-intercept of the normal line at $x_0$?  [Hint:  you just found its slope, and $(x_0,x_0^2)$ is a point on it.]

Given that the $y$-intercept of the normal line is $\dfrac32$ and $x_0>0$, what is $x_0$?

Above you got the slope of the normal line at $x_0$ in terms of $x_0$; this is $a$.

Here is how I picture it, with the parabola in red, the tangent line in blue, and the normal line in green:

[image]

Comment: As I understand from your steps equation will be ➡ 2x=(x^2-3/2)/x-0 Then answer will be uncorrect!

Comment: equation for what?  that's not what I got; please report your answers to each step

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Solve the equation $$x^2-ax-\frac{3}{2}=0$$ and set the discriminant equal to zero and determine the variable $a$.